# mocha tests with database connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm using [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) to test database models in mongoose.   I have before hooks setup that create my connection:

```
let Dbs;
before(() => {
  return db.then(res => {
      Dbs = res;
  });
});
```

This db promise actually is returning a number of models.  But in any case it's connecting to the db and returning an object with some models.

The issue I'm having is that with multiple tests I get the error `MongoError: authentication or logout allready in process`.

I've tried using `after()` to close connections, but still throws the error.  Is there a better way to handle this? I do need to be able to confirm the connection via promise as oppose to just tossing a `mongoose.connect` at the top.

Thanks